# $\mu(X) \lt \infty$. Then $f_k \to f$ in measure iff for any subsequence $k_l$, there is a subsequence $k_{l_n}$ such that $f_{k_{l_n}}\to f$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\mu(X) \lt \infty$. Then $f_k \to f$ in measure iff for any subsequence $k_l$, there is a subsequence $k_{l_n}$ such that $f_{k_{l_n}}\to f$ a.e.

I can show the only if part by using the theorem that if $f_k \to f$ in measure then there is a subsequence converging to $f$ a.e.

However, I can't show the other part. I'm trying to use the finiteness of the measure, but I am out of ideas. How can I show this? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: This is a good question. I want to say that you can show from this that it "Cauchy converges in measure" and then you can show somehow that this is sufficient to guarantee that it converges in measure, but I will look into it, since I know I've seen this proof before.

Comment: If $f_k\xrightarrow{\mu}f$, then $\mu\{|f_{k_l}-f|\ge\epsilon\}>\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and subsequence $f_{k_l}$. Take a further subsequence $f_{k_l'}$ which converges a.e. to $f$... (since $\mu(X)<\infty$, $f_{k_l'}\to f$ a.u.)

Comment: @Norbert https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Topology

Answer (score 1):

In every metric space $(X,d)$ a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ if and only if every subsequence $x_{n_k}$ has a further subsequence converging to $x$
(easy proof by contradiction). All you need to now is thus that convergence in measure is convergence in a metric space (e.g. $d(f,g)=\int \min\lbrace 1,|f(x)-g(x)|\rbrace \, d\mu(x)$ is a suitable metric on the space of equivalence classes of $\mu$-a.e. equal measurable functions) and that a.e. convergence implies convergence in measure.

A funny application of the characterization is that (for most measures $\mu$) a.e. convergence is *not* convergence with respect to a metric.

Answer (score 1):

I will do the forward direction:

**Theorem:** Let $(X,\mathbf{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and suppose $\{f_n\}$ be measurable with $f_n \to f$ in measure. Then if $\mu(X)<\infty$, we have $f_{n_k} \to f$ pointwise a.e. for some subsequence $n_k$.

**Proof:**

We have that for given $\epsilon>0$

$$\mu(\{x \in X: \vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert >\epsilon\})=0.$$

So take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2^k}$ and let $n_k$ be such that if $n \geq n_k$, then

$$\mu(\{x \in X: \vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert >\frac{1}{2^k}\}) \leq \frac{1}{2^k}.$$

Then if

$$A_k:=\{x \in X : \vert f_n(a)-f(x) \vert >\frac{1}{2^k}\},$$

we have that

\begin{align}
\mu(\cup_k A_k)&\leq \sum_k \mu(A_k)\\
&\leq \sum_k \frac{1}{2^k}\\
&<\infty
\end{align}

Thus we conclude that

$$\mu(\lim_{k \to \infty} \sup A_k)=0$$

which implies

$$f_{n_k} \to f$$

pointwise for almost every $x$.